# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. while running React Native Project

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I was running my existing React Native Project in my real android device. Then somehow this error pop up. The error are always about "cannot find symbol". I have JDK and SDK and add into my system variables. But I still do not know why it gives me error like this. As I remember, I just downgrade the version of react-native.

> :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>   D:\rnprojects\firstproject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
>   import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
>                            ^
>     symbol:   class ReactApplication
>     location: package com.facebook.react
>   D:\rnprojects\firstproject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
>   import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
>                            ^
>     symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
>     location: package com.facebook.react
>   D:\rnprojects\firstproject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
>   public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
>                                                               ^
>     symbol: class ReactApplication
>   D:\rnprojects\firstproject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>     private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
>                   ^
>     symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
>     location: class MainApplication
>   D:\rnprojects\firstproject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
>     public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
>            ^
>     symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
>     location: class MainApplication
>   D:\rnprojects\firstproject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainActivity.java:5: error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPackages() in ReactActivity
>   public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
>          ^
>   D:\rnprojects\firstproject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>     private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
>                                                          ^
>     symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
>     location: class MainApplication
>   D:\rnprojects\firstproject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:35: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>     @Override
>     ^
>   8 errors
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>     Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
        repositories {
           jcenter()
        }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
     }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
             // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
             url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Build.gradle/app:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.emptyprojecttemplate"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

 // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
 // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
 task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
     from configurations.compile
     into 'libs'
 }
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812898/react-native-android-appcompiledebugjava-error. Are you using React Native Navigation? Also which versions are you using?

Comment: I'm not using React Native navigation because this project is new. I have react 16.3.1, react-native-cli 2.0.1 , react-native 0.55.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stacktrace starts with : `error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication` this seems to suggest it cannot find the React Library import.

I'm going to include a answer on Github for you, read here:

https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/294

(Btw, this relates to your build.gradle in `/your-project/android/build.gradle`)

In case anyone else is experiencing the same issue: make sure you correctly add new repositories. According to Android docs every maven repo should be in its own maven {} block.

That's why

```
maven {
    // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    url 'some new extra repo'
}
```

breaks dependencies.
The correct version is

```
maven {
    // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
}
maven {
    url 'some new extra repo'
}
```

**UPDATE**

As the above isn't solving your issue and your build.gradle(s) look good (to me). I'll include some other solutions :

Upgrade RN and RN-cli as advised here:

[Cannot resolve symbol ReactApplication/ReactNativeHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120454/cannot-resolve-symbol-reactapplication-reactnativehost)

Another here:

[FAILURE: Build failed with an exception in react-native Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471679/failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-in-react-native-android)

Another here:

[React native android error: cannot find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501382/react-native-android-error-cannot-find-symbol)

**Last resort**

It *may* be worth in just creating a new test project (with the latest versions) like `react-native init anotherproject` to see if that runs.

Comment: So I will just copy it?

Comment: In my case there is no "url 'some new extra repo'"

Comment: Can you include your build.gradle in your original question. The 'some extra repo' is just an example of how to add another url in maven. It's not a valid URL.

Comment: @LizaCatherineOmbyaw - can you also include your app/build.gradle your root one looks good.

Comment: @LizaCatherineOmbyaw- it's located in `your-project/android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: It worked now by using `react-native init projectname'. I am just following the tutorial in udemy haha but gives me error. Because he is using `create-react-native-app projectname` for expo then ejecting the project. Can you explain why it gives me error like that?

Comment: @LizaCatherineOmbyaw I'm not sure, I haven't used that! If you could accept and upvote the answer that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue recently, so I would like the readers to know what I did to get the app working. Initially the app wouldn't even launch so I used 'react-native init' command to get it to work. But the app still wouldn't launch and it gave me a server error, so I found the solution on this link for it :
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21310 and followed this suggestion:

```
npm add @babel/runtime
npm install
```

My app started working like a charm !